# How can I check for missing files in R?

Tags: r

I have a folder full of files with these names

```
ts.01094000.crest
ts.01100600.crest
```

I read dataframe DFX and try to find corresponding files with that filename and perform some operations. If it doesn't exist, I want to skip it and capture it's name. If it exists, I want to move to the else statement. But I am getting this error

```
Error in if (!file.exists(grep(dfx$gauge[i], allCrestFiles, value = T))) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Code:

```
allFiles <- list.files(path='F:/files/', full.names = TRUE)

a<-0

for(i in 1:nrow(dfx))
{
  if(!file.exists(grep(dfx$gauge[i], allFiles, value = T)))
  {
    a[i]<- grep(dfx$gauge[i], allFiles, value = T)
    next
  }

  else
  {
   pFile <- grep(dfx$gauge[i], allFiles, value = T)
   pDat <- fread(pFile) 
  }
}
```

**dfx**

```
structure(list(gauge = c(1094000L, 1100600L, 1100600L, 1100600L, 
1100600L, 1100600L, 1100600L, 1100600L, 1100600L, 1100600L), 
    eventID = c(2L, 6L, 10L, 43L, 52L, 53L, 60L, 62L, 70L, 71L
    ), start = c("5/14/2006 21:00", "10/21/2011 6:15", "8/29/2011 13:00", 
    "5/14/2002 19:00", "9/28/2008 9:00", "7/24/2008 23:30", "5/26/2005 9:15", 
    "9/19/2004 15:30", "5/31/2002 5:30", "6/24/2003 1:45"), end = c("5/16/2006 17:45", 
    "10/22/2011 3:45", "8/30/2011 18:45", "5/16/2002 0:15", "9/29/2008 22:00", 
    "7/27/2008 13:00", "5/28/2005 6:00", "9/20/2004 11:45", "5/31/2002 16:00", 
    "6/24/2003 21:15"), peakt = c("5/15/2006 14:00", "10/21/2011 20:45", 
    "8/29/2011 22:45", "5/15/2002 7:00", "9/28/2008 22:15", "7/25/2008 21:30", 
    "5/27/2005 4:15", "9/19/2004 23:15", "5/31/2002 10:15", "6/24/2003 9:30"
    ), fd = c(44.75, 21.5, 29.75, 29.25, 37, 61.5, 44.75, 20.25, 
    10.5, 19.5), tp = c(17, 14.5, 9.75, 12, 13.25, 22, 19, 7.75, 
    4.75, 7.75), rt = c(27.75, 7, 20, 17.25, 23.75, 39.5, 25.75, 
    12.5, 5.75, 11.75), startTime = structure(c(1147640400, 1319177700, 
    1314622800, 1021402800, 1222592400, 1216942200, 1117098900, 
    1095607800, 1022823000, 1056419100), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), peakTime = structure(c(1147701600, 1319229900, 
    1314657900, 1021446000, 1222640100, 1217021400, 1117167300, 
    1095635700, 1022840100, 1056447000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), endTime = structure(c(1147801500, 1319255100, 
    1314729900, 1021508100, 1222725600, 1217163600, 1117260000, 
    1095680700, 1022860800, 1056489300), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .Names = c("gauge", 
"eventID", "start", "end", "peakt", "fd", "tp", "rt", "startTime", 
"peakTime", "endTime"), class = "data.frame")
```

**WORKING SOLUTION**

```
  if((length(v<-grep(dfx$gauge[i], allFiles, value = T))>0 && !file.exists(v))
     {
      a[i]<- dfx$gauge[i]
      next
  }
```

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION THAT WORKS**

```
allFiles <- list.files(path='F:/files/', full.names = TRUE)

a<-0

for(i in 1:nrow(dfx))
{
  fileNamex <- grep(dfx$gauge[i], allFiles, value = T)
  if(identical(fileNamex, character(0))
  {
    a[i]<- dfx$gauge[i]
    next
  }

  else
  {
   pDat <- fread(fileNamex) 
  }
}
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**: 'input' must be a single character string containing a file name, a command, full path to a file, a URL starting 'http[s]://', 'ftp[s]://' or 'file://', or the input data itself

Why is fread getting triggered? What am I doing wrong with the control?

Comment: list.files(path = "", pattern = ".crest") - this will only return those file names that are present in that folder

Comment: You need to first make sure that `grep` has matched something before calling `file.exists`, e.g. `length(grep(dfx$gauge[i], allCrestFiles, value = TRUE)) > 0` must be true.

Comment: @joel.wilson Not sure why I need to do that. I have only those .crest files in that folder and nothing else. Can you please explain.

Comment: Yeah, grep gives a vector of length zero when it doesn't find something. You can do a compound test like `if (length(v <- grep(...)) && file.exists(v)) ...`

Comment: @nrussell Thank you. Could you point me how to do that. I couldn't find examples...

Comment: @maximusdooku See Frank's comment.

Comment: Not sure if I am doing it correctly. And I see an error message still. Could you please check what I have added.

Comment: If it worked, then post your solution as an answer below.

Comment: It hasn't. I would need some help...

Comment: `file.exists(v)`: you are passing a vector of file names to `file.exists`, but it expects a single file name. You need to iterate over `v` and call `file.exists` on its individual elements, e.g. using `sapply` or a `for` loop.

Comment: @nrussell Sorry, I am not sure how to do that actually. Though I understand what you are saying

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, v is simply character(0)

Comment: @nrussell I don't need the URL, so it will be a[i]<- dfx$gauge[i]. I changed it but I continue to have the error. Also, isn't v just one file name inside the loop?

Comment: @zx8754 The fread is getting triggered for a file that doesn't exist. What am I doing wrong with the transfer of control using next?

Comment: Oh, didn't notice before that you were using `fread`. Here's what I do: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/data.table/4456/using-list-columns-to-store-data/15561/reading-in-many-related-files#t=201611151947045066329 If you need to test whether a file exists, you can filter with `sapply` like `fileDT[sapply(file.exists, fn), contents := .(lapply(fn, fread))]`

Comment: @Frank Thanks. I also posted a possible solution. It works for me. Thank you.

Comment: If you have a solution that works for you, you could post it as an answer here (rather than editing the question). That's the usual/preferred usage of the site, I think.

Comment: I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy to learn better ways to do this. But I think this works.

```
allFiles <- list.files(path='F:/files/', full.names = TRUE)

a<-0

for(i in 1:nrow(dfx))
{
  fileNamex <- grep(dfx$gauge[i], allFiles, value = T)
  if(identical(fileNamex, character(0))
  {
    a[i]<- dfx$gauge[i]
    next
  }

  else
  {
   pDat <- fread(fileNamex) 
  }
}
```